# Junit Jupiter 5 (Intellij) Not recognizing import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test Class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit5

I created a simple java app using gradle init. I am using Intellij 2021.2.2.

When i build the project i am getting following.

[image]

```
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java application project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the 'Building Java & JVM projects' chapter in the Gradle
 * User Manual available at https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/building_java_projects.html
 */

plugins {
    // Apply the application plugin to add support for building a CLI application in Java.
    id 'application'
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.2')
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainClass = 'JunitPOC.App'
}


test{
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.named('test') {
    // Use JUnit Platform for unit tests.
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Looking into the dependencies i can see that all the dependencies are in the test compile & runtime path.

[image]

Looking a bit deeper into the sources i found that Intellij is not picking up the source file for junit.api jar just for Test Class correctly. All the other classes i can refer to.

[image]

Has anybody run into this issue? Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Have you tried restarting IntelliJ and deleting all caches?

Comment: @johanneslink Yep, already tried. FYI i am using MAC version

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it working after going into FILE > Manage IDE Settings > Restore Default Settings.